# ODE:Corresponding first-order system is still linear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Proof that when you convert a nth-order linear ODE to a first order ODE, the corresponding first-order system is still linear.**

Hi,
A linear ODE in explizit form:
$x^{(k)} (t) =G(t, x(t),x'(t),..,x^{(k-1)} (t))$

Which means:

$x_1^{(k)} (t)=G_1(t, x(t),x'(t),..,x^{(k-1)} (t))$

$\vdots$

$x_d^{(k)} (t)=G_d(t, x(t),x'(t),..,x^{(k-1)} (t))$

The general form of a linear ODE is:
$(\*) x_i^{(k)}= g_i(t) + \sum_{l=1}^d \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} f_{i,j,l} (t) x_l^{(j)}$

*Proof with induction after the grade of the ODE*

Base: k=1 trivial

Induction-Step

Convert a linear ODE with k+1th grade $x^{(k+1)} (t) =G(t, x(t),x'(t),..,x^{(k)} (t))$ with:
$y:= x'(t)$, that means $(y_1,..,y_d)= (x'_1(t),..,x'_d(t))$

So we have $y_i^{(k)} = g_i (t) + \sum_{l=1}^{d}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} f_{i,j+1,l} (t) y_l^{(j)} + \sum_{l=1}^n f_{i,0, l} (t) x_i(t)$

How i should convert the equation to see that it is a linear System with kth grade(form the form (*)). The last term with $x_i(t)$ don´t fit in the form like in (*).
When I have this i can apply the induction hypothesis.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no induction needed for this.

Assume we are given a linear inhomogeneous  ODE of order $n$ for a vector-valued unknown function $t\mapsto x(t)\in{\mathbb R}^d\>$:
$$x^{(n)}(t)=g(t)+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} A_j(t) x^{(j)}(t)\ .\tag{1}$$
Here the given inhomogeneity $g$ is vector-valued, and the $A_j(t)$ are $d\times d$ matrices.

In order to convert $(1)$ into a system of first order ODE's one  introduces the *jet-extension* of $x(\cdot)$ as follows: Put
$$y_j(t):=x^{(j)}(t)\qquad(0\leq j\leq n-1)\ .$$
Each $y_j(\cdot)$ is an ${\mathbb R}^d$-valued function, so that
$$y(t):=(y_0(t),y_1(t),\ldots, y_{n-1}(t))\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times d}$$
has $nd$ components in all.

The function $t\mapsto y(t)$ obviously fulfills the linear first order ODE
$$\eqalign{y_0'(t)&=y_1(t)\cr 
y_1'(t)&=y_2(t)\cr &\ \>  \vdots\cr
y_{n-2}'(t)&=y_{n-1}(t)\cr
y_{n-1}'(t)&=g(t)+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} A_j(t) y_j(t)\ .\cr}\tag{2}$$
After unpacking we obtain a system of $nd$ scalar equations. Most of them are **very** simple:
$$y_{r,\>k}'(t)=y_{r+1,\>k}(t)\qquad(0\leq r<n-1, \ 1\leq k\leq d)\ .$$
Only the equations
$$y_{n-1,\>k}'(t)=\ldots\qquad(1\leq k\leq d)$$
look more complicated. Of course one can write $(2)$ in matrix form (plus the inhomogeneity). The resulting matrix is of type $nd\times nd$, but has mostly  zeros and a lot of ones.

Comment: This is not a comment; it is an answer. For the rest see my edit.

Comment: Sry for my mistakes my english is not the best.Is it not correct to transform the n-1 equations like above in my comment? I only ask because we defined an ode as linear when it has the form i marked as (/*) or in matrix-notation, how you described it. So i think i should transform $y'_r (t)=y_{r+1} (t) $ with $r \in \{0,..,n-2\} $ into the matrix-form above -  that i see that the equations are linear.

Comment: What you have tried does not lead anywhere. It is absolutely essential to introduce a great number of new unknown functions (my $y_j(\cdot)$) in order to arrive at a first order system. – This is my last word on this matter.